# Cancellation Fee

Tags: cancellations, fees-and-charges, covid-19, malaysia-airlines

have booked the flight from Kathmandu to Sydney on Malaysian Airlines. Now, I would like to cancel the flight amid Coronavirus fear. Could anyone suggest how much will be the cancellation charge or if there is no charge for cancellation?

Comment: When did you book and when are you due to fly? Have you checked the T&C of your booking?

Answer (score 0):

For Malaysian airlines, you can use this form to ask for refund.

https://www.malaysiaairlines.com/my/en/advisory/coronavirus-entry-restrictions.html?123